# Return list of string using await and async

Tags: c#, azure, async-await

- I have a ASP.NET (4.5) website deployed on organizations tenant azure environment.
- It has a functionality to upload/download/delete the file(any type) to/from the network location (nas drives we call it) e.g. \nas8782\xyz\abc\
- upload/download/delete are working fine (see code below). We use CloudSdk.Azure library which is created by our Azure team.

  - nasClient.UploadAsync
  - nasClient.DownloadAsync
  - nasClient.DeleteAsync
  - **nasClient.ListFilesAsync**

> FileService.cs

```
using CloudSdk.Azure;

private string userId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userId"].ToString();
    private string userPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userPassword"].ToString();
    private string baseNasLocation = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["baseNasLocation"].ToString();
    string env = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["env"].ToString().ToUpper();

public async Task Upload(string fileName, string fileToSave, string projectID)
    {
        var nasClient = new NasClient(userId, userPassword);
        var localFiles = new List<string>();
        localFiles.Add(fileToSave);
        await nasClient.UploadAsync(baseNasLocation + env + @"\" + projectID + @"\", localFiles);
}
public async Task Download(string fileToDownload, string projectID)
    {
        var nasClient = new NasClient(userId, userPassword);
        Stream stream2 = nasClient.DownloadAsync(baseNasLocation + env + @"\" + projectID + @"\" + fileToDownload).Result;
        var appPath2 = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~\\TempUpload");
        var localFullPath2 = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", appPath2, fileToDownload);
        using (var fileStream2 = System.IO.File.Create(localFullPath2))
        {
            stream2.CopyTo(fileStream2);
        }
}


 public async Task Delete(string fileToDelete, string projectID)
    {
        var nasClient = new NasClient(userId, userPassword);
        Task stream2 = nasClient.DeleteAsync(baseNasLocation + env + @"\" + projectID + @"\" + fileToDelete);
}
```

I call these function from my default.aspx.cs page

```
private void Download(string fileName)
    {
        FileService fObj = new FileService();
        var task = Task.Run(async () => { await fObj.Download(fileName, projectId.ToString()); });
        task.Wait();
    }
 private void Delete(string fileName)
    {
        FileService fObj = new FileService();
        var task = Task.Run(async () => { await fObj.Delete(fileName, projectId.ToString()); });
        task.Wait();
    }
private void Upload(string fileName, string fileToSave)
    {
        FileService fObj = new FileService();
  var task = Task.Run(async () => { await fObj.Upload(fileName, fileToSave, projectId.ToString()); });
        task.Wait();
    }
```

**ISSUE**

-This CloudSdk.Azure library has another function call ListFilesAsync, It gets the list of all the files present in the path provided.

I am using below code to do the same but unable to get it.

If I call this Fileservice method

without async and await - It runs but keeps running and never returns the result.

```
public  Task<string> ListFileNames(string projectID)
        {
            var nasClient = new NasClient(userId, userPassword);
            string nasPath = baseNasLocation + env + @"\" + projectID + @"\"; 

            var content =  nasClient.ListFilesAsync(nasPath).Result;
            //return content;
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <Task<string>> (content); 
        }
```

With Async and await - It throws compile error > 
 *'string' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

```
 public async Task<string> ListFileNames(string projectID)
        {
            var nasClient = new NasClient(userId, userPassword);
            string nasPath = baseNasLocation + env + @"\" + projectID + @"\"; 

            var content = await nasClient.ListFilesAsync(nasPath).Result;
            //return content;
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <Task<string>> (content); 
        }
```

How I am calling this method from aspx.cs page > How do I get the result back ?

```
  var task = Task.Run(async () => { await fObj.ListFileNames(projectId.ToString()); });
        task.Wait();
```

Sorry for the long question, I just want to describe as much as possible.
**I am new to this await and async, will really appreciate all the help.**

Comment: You need to do `await nasClient.ListFilesAsync(nasPath)`, just like you do in all other places (such as `await nasClient.UploadAsync(...)`)

Comment: In await call you don't need `Result` in the end, simply call 
`var content = await nasClient.ListFilesAsync(nasPath)` and then 
`return content`, you don't need `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <Task<string>>`, it will automatically wrap the result into `Task<string>`

Comment: Let me try all the suggestions mentioned. Will inform.

Comment: @SaK I recommend reading Stephen Cleary's [blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and its _many_ articles about async/await. I've learned a lot from it.

Comment: @john Thanks for link, will definitely have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Following shall be your implementation:

```
  public async Task<string> ListFileNames(string projectID)
    {
        var nasClient = new NasClient(userId, userPassword);
        string nasPath = baseNasLocation + env + @"\" + projectID + @"\"; 

        return await nasClient.ListFilesAsync(nasPath);
    }
```

- No Calling `Result` in the await call
- No Deserialization to `Task<string>`, it will automatically wrap the result in a `Task<T>`
- `Result`, `Wait` are blocking calls for `Task` and not inline with Async-Await, since operations are going on Asynchronously. In few cases you may use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, but I don't find too many use case for it.
- Async method can have return type of `Task` or `Task<T>`, where result is automatically wrapped by design.

Way Async Await works is for a true Async / IO based operation, it will release the calling context, while operation takes place in the background, thus increasing system scalability

Comment: I made an edit - how I am calling this method from aspx.cs , please see  and let me know if I need to change that.

Comment: Instead of Task.Wait(), use `await`, since your calling method is itself async, you can do the following: `await fObj.ListFileNames(projectId.ToString());`, no need to even wrap inside a `Task.Run`, since you are calling an Async method

Comment: Even if you use the `Task.Run`, which is not required, then still it shall be `await Task ` (will release calling thread) not `Task.Wait()` (will hold the thread)

Comment: Thanks, let me try once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Task.Result to get the result of a Task in a synchronous fashion.

string result = Task.Result;

Also, you shouldn't use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to create a Task. I'm not sure what you are trying to do there. You can use a JObject which allows dynamic access.